# confused of $this in cakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.2

I got a few lines of codes in a Model in cakePHP 1.26:

```
function beforeSave() { 
        $this->data['User']['pswd'] = md5($raw['User']['pswd']);              
         return true;
                         } // this beforeSave() works
```

The code above has been tested and it is working in my database.
Yet, I am not sure if I can understand it well, 
so, I re-wrote the code in other way, and it just failed to work then.

```
 function beforeSave() { 
            $raw=$this->data;       
            $raw['User']['pswd'] = md5($raw['User']['pswd']);                    
             return true;
                             } // this beforeSave() failed to work
```

Why the second method can not work?

Comment: The first method can't work as is. The variable `$raw` is not defined within `beforeSave`. Are you omitting something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line:

```
$raw=$this->data
```

You're just assigning `$this->data` by value to `$raw`. So when you change `$raw`'s array data, `$this->data` isn't affected by the change.

Besides, you're totally changing the meaning of your code. What you end up doing is **replacing** `$raw`'s data with `$this->data` from your model. I've not worked with CakePHP before, but I assume `$raw` already contains all the raw data you've received through some kind input, while `$this->data` in your model contains the older version of your model data (for example, an older password that the user was going to change). Your changed code will just erase all the new data in `$raw`, which I don't think is what you intend to do judging from your first code example.

To give you a little explanation of this line:

```
$this->data['User']['pswd'] = md5($raw['User']['pswd']);
```

It's pretty simple: the `pswd` item in the `User` array of `$this->data` is set as the MD5 checksum of the `pswd` in the `User` array of `$raw`.

Answer (score 2):

```
if($this->data['Register']['password'] == $this->data['Register']['confirm_password'])
{
   return true;
}
else
{
   return false;
}
```

Use this in your model's beforeSave function()